# When should don't be used and doesn't?

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement

When should we use don't in a sentence and when should we use doesn't?

For example:

> A few rich people doesn't make a country rich.
>
> A few rich people don't make a country rich.

Which is the appropriate usage?

Comment: **Don't = do not** - is for plural, **Doesn't = does not** - is for singular. Generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the verb agrees in number with the number of the *grammatical* subject, here, **a few rich people**, which is plural.

However, it is not uncommon that the verb will agree in number with the *semantic* subject, with an idea the speaker has *in mind*:

> a few rich people <sup>paraphrase in context:</sup> *the fact that a country has a few rich people*

and in that case the number of the verb would be singular to agree with the thing the speaker has in mind.

In formal writing, we expect the number of the verb to agree with the number of the *grammatical* subject.

Comment: So do you mean to say it could be either don't or doesn't depending upon context?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **could be**.  Allowed to be? Or "one might encounter"?  In formal contexts, grammatical agreement is the norm.  In conversational contexts, one might encounter grammatical disagreement which can often be explained as  semantic agreement.